# Yii ClinkPager doesn't work on Ajax Request

Tags: ajax, yii, pagination

Firstly, when the page gets loaded, ClinkPager works properly with all the paging correctly displayed. 
But when Ajax Request is sent, the results get populated correctly with all the paging.
But clicking on the next or another page in the Paging, the previous data gets loaded and also paging shows different sequence.

```
/*Controller action to fetch the records and apply the pagination*/
//---------------------------------------------------------------
public function actionGetUser($user_id=null)
{
$user_domain= (isset($_POST['user_domain'])?$_POST['user_domain']: null);

$model=new UserSearch();
$criteria=new CDbCriteria();
//If Category/Title are also specified for search, then its an Ajax request.
if((isset($_POST['ajax_search'])) && ($_POST['ajax_search']==1))
{
    //Change the search criteria accordingly
    $criteria->select="*";

            if($user_domain!= null)
    {
                //Adding criteria to search for ideas of specific domain
        $criteria->addCondition("user_domain=".$usr_domain);
    }
}
    //Retrieve the users.
$searchData = $model->search();

//Count the no. of results retrieved.
$count=UserSearch::model()->count($criteria);

//Enable pagination
$pages=new CPagination($count);
$searchData->setPagination($pages);
$pages->applyLimit($criteria);

//Search for ideas satisfying that criteria
$models=userSearch::model()->findAll($criteria);

    if((isset($_POST['ajax_search'])) && ($_POST['ajax_search']==1))
{
    //Rendering the respective page
    $this->renderPartial('renderOnAjax', array(
                'user' => $models,
                            'pages' => $pages,
            'user_count'=>$count
        ));
    }
    else
{
    //Rendering the respective page
    $this->render('render', array(
                'user' => $models,
                'pages' => $pages,
            'user_count'=>$count
        ));
}
}
//------------------------------------------------------------

/*render page*/
//------------------------------------------------------------
<div>
<div class="userInfo" id="user_search_result">
    <?php $this->renderPartial("renderOnAjax",array('user'=>$user, 'pages'=>$pages));?>
</div>
</div>
//------------------------------------------------------------

/*renderOnAjax Page*/
//------------------------------------------------------------
<?php 
$i=0; 
$count=count($user);?>
<?php while($i!=$count) {?>
<?php $row=$count[$i];?>
<div class="Box">
/*Some contain to display...*/

</div>
<?php $i++;?>
<?php } ?>

<div class="row">
    <?php  $this->widget('CLinkPager', array(
            'pages' => $pages
        ));
    ?>
</div>
```

//---------------------------------------------------------

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<?php $this->renderPartial("renderOnAjax",array('user'=>$user, 'pages'=>$pages),false,true);?>
```

Here is official documentioan for renderPartial

```
public string renderPartial(string $view, array $data=NULL, boolean $return=false, boolean $processOutput=false)

$view=string    name of the view to be rendered. See getViewFile for details about how the view script is resolved.
$data=array data to be extracted into PHP variables and made available to the view script
$return=boolean whether the rendering result should be returned instead of being displayed to end users
$processOutput=boolean  whether the rendering result should be postprocessed using processOutput.
{return}    string  the rendering result. Null if the rendering result is not required.
```

**EDIT:**
The above scheme works for ajax call renderPArtials. You should try this where you are rendering ajax request in controller action like

```
 $this->renderPartial('renderOnAjax', array(
                'user' => $models,
                            'pages' => $pages,
            'user_count'=>$count
        ),false,true);
```

Comment: I have added the parameter, but still the same problem exist.

Comment: ok, then i am not sure if its happening due t that, But please try 4 different combinations like (false,false), (false,true),(true,false),(true,true). Then see if it works or not.